# Create Chart with Multiple Dimensions and a Reference Line

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/charts) from Microsoft describes separate instructions for creating a chart with multiple dimensions and adding a reference line.

I'm trying to do both at the same time.  I'm using the following query to measure memory usage across multiple environments:

```
Perf
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
| where (CounterName == "% Committed Bytes In Use")
| summarize avg(CounterValue) by Computer, bin(TimeGenerated, 15m)
| render timechart
```

If I try adding `| extend Threshold = 50`, the query still works correctly, but the reference line does not show.

Does anyone know if there is a way to get the reference line showing when I am already using multiple dimensions?

**EDIT:**

As recommended, here is the full script I'm running:

```
Perf
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
| where (CounterName == "% Committed Bytes In Use")
| summarize avg(CounterValue) by Computer, bin(TimeGenerated, 15m)
| extend Threshold = 50
| render timechart
```

And here are the results with the reference line missing:

[image]

Comment: you may want to share the full query (to clarify where you added that line), as well as include a snapshot of the actual output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this query, it adds additional row for each `TimeGenerated` row with fixed value of `50` for `Threshold`.

> By inserting additional row for each `TimeGenerated`, it makes sure that the `Threshold` is set to a fixed value and displays line in the `timechart`.

```
let tab_Perf =
    Perf
    | where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
    | where (CounterName == "% Committed Bytes In Use")
    | summarize avgValue = avg(CounterValue) by Computer, bin(TimeGenerated, 15m)
    ;
tab_Perf
| union
    (
        tab_Perf
        | distinct TimeGenerated
        | project TimeGenerated, Computer = "Threshold", avgValue = 50.0
    )
| render timechart
```

[image]

This may not be perfect solution, but at least it works :-).